# FIR Filter on Cortex M0

Tags: microcontroller, arm, dsp, fir

Is it possible to implement basic DSP (such as an FIR Filter) on a Cortex M0 or is the architecture too limited?

Comment: You can implement any algorithm on any turing-complete machine. So, yeah. Also: Cortex-M0s can be had in the 50 MHz range; they have a full 32bit ARM/Thumb instruction set and come with large memories. Not really what I'd call "too limited". The question really is how long your FIR is, and how fast you need the results :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. An FIR filter is essentially a cascade of multiplication, addition and registers

**y[n] = b[0] * x[n] + b[1] * x[n-1] + b[2] * x[n-2] + ...+ b[numTaps-1] * x[n-numTaps+1]**

What makes Digital Signal Processors (DPS's ) so attractive for this type of operation is a lot of optimisation effort went into providing a platform best suited for Digital Signal Processing.

So can such algorithms be implemented on non-DSP platforms? of course. You can implement them in Excel if you so wish and you have a need to post-process data. The time to execute such filtering algorithms may present a bottleneck in your uP designs and this is where tradeoffs in implementation is required

https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__FIR.html

http://wseas.us/e-library/conferences/2012/Prague/ECC/ECC-73.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. You can implement any kind of DSP on a Cortex M0. Practically it will depend on the size of your filter (ie. RAM usage) and required speed (if it is real-time). Of course the implementation will have to be fixed-point, as M0 does not have a floating-point unit (so floating point operations are slow).

I recommend using [CMSIS DSP](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/index.html) which is a DSP library provided by ARM and optimized specially for their cores.

Comment: It does not have to be fixed point. Floating point can be implemented in software too. Just computes slower.

Answer (score 0):

I once implemented an adaptive least-mean-squared filter algorithm on a 16-bit processor running at 3 MHz, so yes of course you can.

Now, if you had given us information about the filter size and sample rate we might have been able to give a better answer.